# Automatically Executing a PHP File on a Timed Interval

Tags: javascript, php

I want to execute one `PHP` file that will clear my chat every 5 minutes, I have the file and when I go to www.mywbsite.com/clear.php my chat is cleaned so the code inside the clear.php is okay.

I want one way to my website to execute that file every 5 minutes, can someone help me? Probably some refresh function or something in javascript or I don't know can someone help me?

my clean.php is only replacing the old file

```
file_put_contents('text.txt', '');
```

Comment: while clearing a chat is smth to display only at the client i strongly recommend you to use Javascript here. jQuery: `$('#myChatLog').html("");`

Comment: Or you could use cron on the server to CURL the clear.php page.

Comment: cron jobs are how you normally do housekeeping

Comment: you have to set cron job on your server

Comment: Do you not have access to `cron`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in multiple ways, what I would suggest you are:

1. You  can write an AJAX call using Javascript / jQuery to call your file every 5 minutes using a setInterval() function.

   var ajax_call = function() {
     //your code ajax code
   };

   var interval = 1000 * 60 * X; // where X is your every X minutes

   setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
2. You can write a CRON job on your server to execute you PHP file every 5 minutes.

   http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Hope it helps :)

Cheers
Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? im using this to refresh some div's

```
refresh();

function refresh()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "clear.php",
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("div.chat").html(result);
        }
    });

    setTimeout(refresh, 300000);
}
```

Comment: 5 minutes = 300.000 milliseconde :)

Comment: @A.Rossi the time was just one example but i will update

Comment: Th op ask for 5 minutes, and you write 50000, i thought it was a mistake from you, np

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax method and also set an interval like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "clear.php",
            success: function(){
                $("#div").html("");
            },
        });
    }, 300000);
});
```

This makes the clear.php page loads every %minutes and after success it emptys the chat box